# C#, GetProperty BindingSource, authorTableAdapter

Tags: c#, reflection, getproperty

i have problem with GetProperty

```
partial class MyForm : Form
{
    ...

    public System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource authorBindingSource = new ...;
    public MethodicalWorkDataSetTableAdapters.authorTableAdapter authorTableAdapter = new ...;

    ...


    public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
    {
        return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
    }

    public void someFunction()
    {
        GetPropValue( this, "authorBindingSource" ); // returns null
    }
}
```

Please help me, function GetPropValue works fine, except "authorTableAdapter" and "authorBindingSource "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `authorTableAdapter` and `authorBindingSource` are [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), not [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). Change `GetProperty` to `GetField`.

Answer (score 0):

use `GetMember` instead of `GetProperty`